# finding the leftside of the number from my query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query which is getting updated on the basis that everytime something goes wrong, it adds 1 to the front of the exists number and every 1 added to the front has a different meaning

so update happens like this

```
update users
              set i = i + 10000
              where username = @username
```

i am writing a query to fetch the extreme 1 on the left side, if it has, display a message

because the number at the right side gets increasing too, so it always has a unique number

like 110

11000

110000

1100000

so if i pick last one and get the first 1 and measures against the remaining numbers count which is 6, i know which issue the user has

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

CAST the number as string and the you can chekc the string for the positions of the one

You can nest the CASE WHEN to the depth that you need

```
SELECT 
  value,
  CASE CHARINDEX('1', CAST(value as CHAR(11))) 
  WHEN 0 THEN 'No number'
  WHEN  1 THEN
   CASE CHARINDEX('1', CAST(value as CHAR(11)), 2) 
     WHEN 0 THEN 'only one 1 at the beginning'
     WHEN 2 THEN 'two ones at the beginning'
     WHEN 3 THEN 'ones at the beginning and at the trind another'
     WHEN 4 THEN 'ones at the beginning and at the forth another'
     ELSE ' First 1 one and then later another'
   END
  WHEN 2 THEN 'only a one at  the third position'
  ELSE 'somewhere a one after the third'
  END
  FROM T
```

| value | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | No number |
| 1 | only one 1 at the beginning |
| 11 | two ones at the beginning |
| 100010 | First 1 one and then later another |
| 100011 | First 1 one and then later another |
| 101000 | ones at the beginning and at the trind another |
| 110000 | two ones at the beginning |
| 100001 | First 1 one and then later another |
| 100000 | only one 1 at the beginning |
| 100 | only one 1 at the beginning |
| 101 | ones at the beginning and at the trind another |
| 10 | only one 1 at the beginning |
| 1000 | only one 1 at the beginning |
| 1001 | ones at the beginning and at the forth another |
| 1010 | ones at the beginning and at the trind another |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cfV8fVH8)

Comment: @nbki am not adding it, i want to see if the length of the numbers on thr ight side and the extra one on the left side match and u if yes, i display a message

Comment: like this `101000
101000
110000`, not i will get the 1 on the left side and match the remaining numbers count, they are 5, so i know its total of 6 with 1 on the left side and remaining on the other side and i know what message to display

Comment: sorry i dont get it, make a fidlle and wanted result

Comment: i can try to fiddle, here is my try http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c4915 @nbk

Comment: i am trying to do this ; 'check to see if "1" is in a specific position. So, in the case of the first one, you would check to see if sub string of the first character is 1 then message. If sub string of second character is 1 then other message.'

Comment: can i also get the length of the number and also length of the number excluding the first number, that would be helpful

Comment: yes see string function, as you know know the different positions, you can calculate length of the substring here all all strung functions to play around with https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: i did like this but how to add it to the existing table excluding the first one

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/XHVXrDU4, excluding the first column

Comment: i did this `select  LEN(value),len(value)-1 as without_1 from t` but not sure, it did from the right side or left side, i want it from left side

Comment: for that the function RIGHt and LEFT are better, simp,ytry them in the provided  fiddle